# about IComponentConnector2

Tags: winrt-xaml, c++-winrt

I have the following code

```
struct MainPage : PageT<MainPage,IComponentConnector,IComponentConnector2>
{...}
```

How `GetBindingConnector` get called? As a comparison, I know if I set the `ConnectionId` attribute on the Xaml page, `IComponentConnector.Connect` will get called. So there must exist some attribute(s) that will trigger `GetBindingConnector`, then what's that? Many thanks!!!

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Button Content="Test" x:ConnectionId="1"/>
</Page>
```

### New Update

1,Using `x:Bind` and `GetBindingConnector` called

```
<Page
    x:Class="BlankApp1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:BlankApp1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Button x:Name="myButton" Content="{x:Bind MyProperty}"/>
</Page>
```

and the dump of xbf

```
PushScopeAddNamespace (prefix=(null), namespace=http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation)
  AddNamespace (prefix=x, namespace=http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml)
  AddNamespace (prefix=local, namespace=using:BlankApp1)
  AddNamespace (prefix=d, namespace=http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008)
  AddNamespace (prefix=mc, namespace=http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006)
  CreateTypeBeginInit (type=Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page)
  SetConnectionId (Id=type=Signed, value=1)
  CheckPeerType (x:Class=BlankApp1.MainPage)
  PushScopeCreateTypeBeginInit (type=Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)
    SetConnectionId (Id=type=Signed, value=2)
    SetName (x:Name=myButton)
  EndInitPopScope
  SetValue (property=Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.UserControl.Content)
EndInitPopScope
```

2, Not using `x:Bind`:

```
<Page
    x:Class="BlankApp1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:BlankApp1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Button x:Name="myButton"/>
</Page>
```

and the dump of xbf

```
PushScopeAddNamespace (prefix=(null), namespace=http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation)
  AddNamespace (prefix=x, namespace=http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml)
  AddNamespace (prefix=local, namespace=using:BlankApp1)
  AddNamespace (prefix=d, namespace=http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008)
  AddNamespace (prefix=mc, namespace=http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006)
  CheckPeerType (x:Class=BlankApp1.MainPage)
  CreateTypeBeginInit (type=Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page)
  PushScopeCreateTypeBeginInit (type=Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)
    SetConnectionId (Id=type=Signed, value=2)
    SetName (x:Name=myButton)
  EndInitPopScope
  SetValue (property=Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.UserControl.Content)
EndInitPopScope
```

3, differences of the 2 dumps
[image]

I'm not sure if this is the root cause that makes difference.

Comment: The element in XAML using **Binding** will generate a call to GetBindingConnector within the generated code file. You could try to use Binding/x:Bind to bind a property with the Content of Button, after Building, you can check it in the YourClass.xaml.g.hpp file.

Comment: If I load the ```.xaml``` file instead of ```.xbf``` file, ```GetBindingConnector``` will never get called, is this true?

Comment: When you use Binding and build the project, it will generate code for GetBindingConnector, after launching the project and initializing the component, GetBindingConnector will be called.